# Icon and left arrow / burger with support action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am starting to use the App Compat library in my app and I am struggling with the action bar icon. My test activity is as simple as

```
[Activity(Label = "MyLabel", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light", Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MyTestActivity : ActionBarActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SupportActionBar.Title = "My Title";
        SupportActionBar.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I am expecting the output as follows:

[image: Action bar with Icon]

However, with the current 22.2.0.0 version of the app compat library, the action bar looks like this:

[image: Actionbar without icon]

Interestingly, when using the 7.18.0 version of Xamarin's v7 App Compat component, the output is as expected (first image) (but that doesn't give me the new features in 22.2.0.0).

Is there any way to achieve the expected (first) output with 22.2.0.0?

Any solution (Xamarin C# or simple Java) would be great!

Comment: If you want the old style you need to use an old version of the support library (pre version 21 I believe). What you see is the new material style

Answer (score 0):

It's a material design thing :)

The appcompat lib's visuals are based on Material Design guidelines.  You're first example is what would be displayed using the previous Holo design guidelines.

if you're going for current design guidelines, the second picture is the 'correct' one and will fit into current android design practices.

Comment: The first was also old `AppCompat` as well. When it comes to Android and it's Fragmentation, always use `AppCompat`.